# Is there a simple way to create a modal button menu on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Plenty of applications seem to do this. For example, go to Apple's mail application and press the "reply" button on the toolbar. You'll get a menu with buttons that say "Reply", "Reply All", "Forward" and "Cancel" that will scroll up from the bottom.

The way I figure I could do this is to create a short view in IB with the buttons I want, present it modally, and right a view controller to handle the buttons.

It seems like this is so common that there must be an easier way to do it (like how easy it is to add to the toolbar and navigation bar).

Is there some widget or shortcut that I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually just a UIActionSheet.  You can create one pretty easily.

http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for. You won't believe how hard it is to find info about something like that on the internet when you have no idea what it is called.

Comment: I feel your pain man.  "You don't know what you don't know."  If this answer is what you were looking for, do me a favor and hit the "checkmark" next to my answer.  Everything around here works off of reputation points as a way of saying "thank you" :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make a view controller with the controls you want in IB and then call `[self presentModalViewController:[[[MyModalViewController alloc] init] autorelease] animated:YES]` on the current view controller.